# KeyError: 'DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME' run building in Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, nativescript

I receive an error when building my nativescript app on Xcode since upgrading to Xcode 13

```
./.build_env_vars.sh: line 454: declare: UID: readonly variable
NSLD: Swift bridging header '*-Swift.h' not found under '/Users/gaetan.delsaux/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mbwsinventoryapp-egjrwafdujqbnuemdmqazirgunfd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mbwsinventoryapp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mbwsinventoryapp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64'
Generating metadata...~/PhpstormProjects/mbws-inventory-app/platforms/ios/internal/metadata-generator/bin ~/PhpstormProjects/mbws-inventory-app/platforms/ios
Python version: 2.7.18 (v2.7.18:8d21aa21f2, Apr 19 2020, 20:48:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build-step-metadata-generator.py", line 41, in <module>
    deployment_target_flag_name = env("DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME")
  File "./build-step-metadata-generator.py", line 14, in env
    return os.environ[env_name]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have looked around but the answered I found were all related to Objective C.

Has anyone face this issues and found a solution?

Comment: are you using macOS 12.3 or newer?

Comment: @Yong yes I user macOs Monterey version 12.3.1

Comment: Then you have to use python3. check nativescript via "ns doctor". You can get more information from https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios

Comment: @GDelsaux I saw this issue happening on macOs Monterey. Make sure that xcode is not 13.3 or higher. At least in my case that solved the issue. Reference: https://answers.sap.com/answers/13611183/view.html

Comment: Is there an alternative solution than breaking the xcode toolchain with a downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade NativeScript to 6.5.5 or above, which contains a patch.

If you're interested in the technical details, or came from another project, keep reading.

---

In Xcode 13.3 and above, the environment variables `DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_NAME` and `DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME` no longer exist.

You can solve this by determining these values manually using `EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME`:

```py
platform = env("EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME")
if platform is "-iphoneos":
    flag = "-miphoneos-version-min"
    target = "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
elif platform is "-iphonesimulator":
    flag = "-mios-simulator-version-min"
    target = "IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
elif platform is "-watchos"
    flag = "-mwatchos-version-min"
    target = "WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
elif platform is "-watchossimulator"
    flag = "-mwatchos-simulator-version-min"
    target = "WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
elif platform is "-appletvos"
    flag = "-mappletvos-version-min"
    target = "APPLETVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
elif platform is "-appletvsimulator":
    flag = "-mappletvsimulator-version-min"
    target = "APPLETVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
else:
    flag = "-mmacosx-version-min"
    target = "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
```

Thanks to the author of https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-jsc/pull/1296 for demonstrating this technique.